# Django Queryset Datetime Filter

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-1.9

I have a column formatted as such in one of my models:

```
TEMP_START = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

And I am attempting to do an exact lookup using queryset syntax such as

```
x.filter(TEMP_START=my_datetime_object) # x can be thought of as y.objects.all()
```

This returns no objects, when it should do more than one. However,

```
x.filter(TEMP_START__date=my_datetime_object.date()).filter(TEMP_START__hour=my_datetime_object.hour)
```

Does return the proper objects (they're hourly). Are direct datetime filters not supported, and thus keywords must be used?

====== Edit with bad results:

```
Searching for: {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31, 2, 0)}

Values in column: [{'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 29, 8, 0)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 29, 14, 0)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 2, 0)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 29, 20, 0)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 8, 0)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 20, 0)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31, 2, 0)}, {'TEMP_START': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 14, 0)}]

Values being returned: []


Code:
    args_timeframe_start = {variables.temp_start: self.ranked_timeframes[rank][variables.temp_start]}
    print(args_timeframe_start)
    print(self.query_data.values(variables.temp_start).distinct())
    query_data = self.query_data.filter(**args_timeframe_start)
    print(query_data.values(variables.temp_start).distinct())
```

Comment: Please show exactly what you're doing, rather than using filler content like `my_datetime_object`. It'll be more helpful for us to see how you're actually doing things, and where variables are coming from.

Comment: Do `TEMP_START` and `my_datetime_object` have exact same values?

Comment: Also note that "exact same" should include hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds and timezone...

Comment: @LudwikTrammer, they are "exactly the same". No timezone assigned to anything. Exactly same y/m/d h:m:s, TZ (none).

Comment: @rnevius: Please see my comment under the Shang's answer. They are coming from the same column and I am looking up the nth one (ranking).

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what is `my_datetime_object` but most likely because DateTime fields contain python `datetime.datetime` objects, `datetime.datetime` objects is composed of year, month, date, hour, minute, second, microsecond. So if you merely compare `date` and `hour`, sure you could get results, but you couldn't guarantee that `my_datetime_object` matches one of the records in your database that has the same minute, second and microsecond.

Try this quickly and you could see what does datetime look like, also [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) about `DateTimeField`:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()
print date
```

Comment: All other fields are zero, and don't have a timezone set (on either object)

Comment: How did you get `my_datetime_object`?

Comment: TEMP_START = models.DateTimeField(null=True). Essentially, I'm ranking the datetimes and looking up the n-th object based on user input. So when I say the objectis in the model's field. It's guaranteed. That's where it came from.

Comment: OK, I couldn't try it out because I don't have your environment. I tried something on my side to take a datetime from my database record field and query on that, django returns the exact result. I guess you need to debug it, try using `pdb` to examine what's `my_datetime_object` at run time.

Comment: I think your filter `args_timeframe_start` is right. It should be dict that with a string of lookup criteria as key and lookup value as value. Check this SO answer to see the exact format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763495/adding-extra-paramaters-to-a-objects-filter-via-dict?answertab=votes#tab-top